# Why can't I use templates members in its specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, class-template

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
public:
    T DataMember;
};

template<>
struct Foo<int>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << DataMember;
    }
};
```

When I try to compile it, it gives an

```
error C2065 'DataMember': undeclared identifier
```

What I want to do is to use templates members in its specialization.

I tried a lot of things and googled the problem for hours, but everything I find is examples that don't use templates members and other questions related to c++ templates, but not the one I need.

Comment: You specialize `Foo<int>` from scratch. `Foo<T>` now has `T DataMember` for all `T` but `int`. You want to add `int DataMember;` field in the specialization.

Comment: Template specialization isn't like inheritance. It doesn't retain things from the "base" unless you override them. Rather, it starts over "from scratch". When you specialize `Foo` for `int`, you' basically telling the compiler to ignore the base template entirely and only pay attention to the code in this specialization for `Foo<int>`.

Comment: You don't show how you intent to use the explicit specialization, but I also suspect that there is a good chance it is not the functionality that you should be using in the first place. It looks like you want either inheritance instead or have `bar` as member of the primary template directly.